# Possible to subscript or change vertex shapes in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

I am visualising a network that of data with three groups, an individual person plus their corresponding company and position. There are differing companies plus positions within the database. I wish to format the figure for publication, so need to print in greyscale. However, I need a method of discriminating one individual from another, according to position and company. I thought a subscript containing a numeric ID for each individual may work.

However, is it possible to subscript part of a vertex label in igraph?

I know the following works for base plots, but what about igraph?

`plot(1,1, main=expression('title'^2))`

Another option could be to assign a different shape to each individual however, I am unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Shapes can be altered using:

`V(a)$shape <- c("circle", "circle", "circle", "circle", "square", "square", "rectangle", "rectangle")`

Then plotted by:

`plot(a, layout = layout, vertex.size = 35,vertex.frame.color= "white",vertex.label.color = "black",vertex.color = V(a)$color,vertex.shape = V(a)$shape,vertex.label.family = "sans",edge.width=E(a)$weight,edge.color="light grey")`

Comment: You can also add subscript in a similar way as in regular plots. Example, `g <- random.graph.game(10, 0.2) ; 
plot(g, vertex.label = parse(text=(paste0(letters[1:10], "[", 1:10, "]")))`